# Converting a Lithium Ion Model from a Foster Network to a Cauer Network

Tags: lithium-ion, passive-networks, modeling

It is possible to convert common thermal RC-models between the Foster form and the Cauer form, as seen here:

[image]

I was wondering if and how this is possible with lithium-ion cell models, which commonly use a voltage source and not a current source, for example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Foster and Cauer models are canonical models for arbitary impedance synthesizing. Those gentlemen were circuit theorists. They decomposed rational s-domain impedance and admittance functions to continued fractions and partial fractions which showed quite clearly the needed component values.

Different decompositions of the same impedance or admittance function give different circuits.

The current source in the heat transfer diagram is the heating power, only resistors and capacitors belong to the impedance synthetizations that Cauer and Foster invented.

I see you have thought that the voltage source in your battery model is somehow in the place of the heat current source. You have totally missed the point. The corresponding part for the current source is the series connection of Uoc and what's connected to the battery terminals They together is what's connected to the impedance circuit. Sorry.

You can transform the impedance circuit  Ro + Up1 + Up2 to Cauer's version but voltage source Uoc and the plain line from the minus of Uoc to minus output terminal without intermediate connections must stay intact. I guess the change is useless because the presented parts have a certain understandable meaning in the behaviour of the battery. Cauer's impedance circuit would be totally abstract.

Comment: Would you be able to share the method of how to do it? Or a link

Comment: Can you at first explain what comfort or flexibility you will get by changing Ro + Up1 + Up2 to another a little different RC network. Uco and the plain wire from its minus pole to -Ut stays.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  See:
K. Murthy and R. Bedford, [*Transformation between Foster and Cauer equivalent networks*](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1084459), in IEEE Transactions on Circuits and Systems, vol. 25, no. 4, pp. 238-239, April 1978, doi: 10.1109/TCS.1978.1084459.  Afraid I don't have access to this document, but it sounds quite direct.

You may also find the original authors' work of interest, though you likely have some work to do to connect them in the way desired.  These include:

Foster, Ronald M., [*A Reactance Theorem*](https://archive.org/details/bstj3-2-259/mode/2up), Bell System Technical Journal, 3: 2. April 1924 pp 259-267.

Cauer, W, *Die Verwirklichung der Wechselstromwiderstände vorgeschriebener Frequenzabhängigkeit*, Archiv für Elektrotechnik, vol 17, pp355–388, 1926.  Offhand, I don't see a translation, unfortunately.

In more practical terms, I'm not too fond of attempting to manipulate lengthy polynomials myself, and I don't have to solve so many of these that it's worth implementing an algorithm; rather, I would simply set up the impedance networks in a simulator or spreadsheet, one with dummy values, and either run a general numerical solver to manipulate the values until error is arbitrarily small, or adjust them by hand and eye to get a slower, rougher approximation.

If you have MATLAB available, it seems there is an out-of-the-box solution: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48042-foster-and-cauer-equivalent-networks It may run in GNU Octave as well, or with minor modification.